# What is the difference between "before_action :only" and "before_action :except" in Rails 5.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm setting up my first rails app (by following instructions from this site: http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#i4:-a-few-gems). In the articles_controller, authentication is required for new, create, edit, update and destroy. We're to figure out how to write the before_action using either `:only` or `:except`.

Although I've tried using the two; I get errors when I used `:except`, but no errors with `:only`. Yet I still don't understand the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Except runs the before action when the condition is false. Only runs the before filter when the condition is true.

```
class Foo
  before_action :log_not_signed_in, except: :signed_in?
  before_action :log_signed_in, only: :signed_in?
end
```

This will run the `log_not_signed_in` method on every action if the use is not signed in, and the `log_signed_in` method if he is.

Hope this helps.